# How to get return value from pagemethods in Jquery..?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How to return true/false from PageMethods to OnclientClick Event..??
Here is the Jquery function that will call on OnClientClick Event of some button.If this function returns true i want to execute some server side methods..? but how to return values to OnClientClick Event..??

Here is my code..

```
function SendFriendReq(FriendReq) {
        PageMethods.CheckFriend(FriendReq, function (ResString) {
        // Here I Want to send True/False to OnClientEvent based on ResStirng value  
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), if your WebMethod is defined like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

You can call it from your page's javascript like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/GetTime",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var time = data.d;
    }
});
```

This is an alternative if you don't want to use the ASP.NET autogenerated javascript proxy. I personally prefer to use jQuery as it is a generic solution that works with most [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) implementations.

Comment: Hi Thomas..Thanks for your Response..You have given solution on return value that is returned from webmethod. But my problem is something different i think..

<asp:imagebutton runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "SendFriendReq(\""+Eval("UserName")+"\")"%>' CommandName="Check/>"

Here OnClientClick event calls function SendFriendReq..I need to either execute or terminate OnRowCommand event depending on SendFriendReq Manipulations..That is i want return True or false to OnClientClick event as shown in Below example..

Comment: Ok, now I see, what you are trying to do is to make your server call a javascript function. But I'm afraid PageMethods doesn't work that way, it is the other way around, the clients are responsible for calling your PageMethods and its result is return to the client in a callback function.

Comment: I guess you could use the [ImageButton Click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.click.aspx) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I solved my problem in the way what you have suggested. But still I don't know whether it possible or not to achieve the thing what i am looking for. I have to do more research on it. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

You can call your PageMethod with the return value like this, if you don't want to pass any parameters then you can just remove them:

```
PageMethods.AddDocumentToCRM(imagedata, retrievedGuid,
    function(result) {
        if (result != null || result != undefined)
            appendMessage("<span style='color:#cE5E04'><b>Document Uploaded.</b></span> <br /><b>Note GUID : </b>" + result + "<br />");
        else
            appendMessage("<span style='color:#cE5E04'<b>Document Uploaded Fail.</b></span>");
        }
    );
```